# JPA: How can an @Embeddable object get a reference to its owner?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a User class that has @Embedded a class Profile. How can I give the instances of Profile a reference to their owner the User class?

```
@Entity
class User implements Serializable  {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @Embedded Profile profile;

   // .. other properties ..
}

@Embeddable
class Profile implements Serializable {

   User user; // how to make this work?

   setURL(String url) {
      if (user.active() ) { // for this kind of usage
         // do something
      }
   }

   // .. other properties ..
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming JPA rather than strictly Hibernate, you might do this by applying `@Embedded` to a getter/setter pair rather than to the private member itself.

```
@Entity
class User implements Serializable {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   @Embedded
   private Profile profile;

   public Profile getProfile() {
      return profile;
   }

   public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
      this.profile = profile;
      this.profile.setUser(this);
   }

   // ...
}
```

However, I would question whether an embedded entity is what you want at all in this case, as opposed to a @OneToOne relationship or simply "flattening" the Profile class into User. The main rationale for @Embeddable is code reuse, which seems unlikely in this scenario.

Comment: My reason for using @Embedded is not code reuse, but to get more focused smaller classes instead of one big unwieldy do it all class.

Comment: Have you considered simple inheritance? In other words, if a "profile" is really information about a Person, and every User "is a" Person, could `class User extends Person` (formerly Profile)? I don't mean to be pedantic, but I've only ever found one good use for `@Embeddable` and, again, it was for code reuse (and because I couldn't be bothered to build the plumbing to map the "embedded" class to a database type).

Comment: I actually favor composition over inheritance. As the user is not just one thing, it really is a composition of different things like, security, profile and settings.

Comment: I choose this as my solution. JPA with AccessType.Property on the embedded fields worked best. The Hibernates annotation @Parent looked promising, but also requires getters and setters on the embedded object and thus does not offer anything better than the pure JPA solution.

Comment: This setter trick worked for me [with ObjectDB too](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/1173). The trick appears also as worth trying for some JPA implementations [under WikiBooks JPA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Example_of_an_Embeddable_object_annotations).

Answer (score 15):

Refer to the official documentation ,section 2.4.3.4. , http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/ , you can  use `@org.hibernate.annotations.Parent` to give the Profile object a back-pointer to its owning User object and implement the getter of the user object .

```
@Embeddable
class Profile implements Serializable {

   @org.hibernate.annotations.Parent
   User user; // how to make this work?

   setURL(String url) {
      if (user.active() ) { // for this kind of usage
         // do something
      }
   }

   User getUser(){
       return this.user;
   }

   // .. other properties ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't find any documentation on this Hibernate feature, do you happen to have a link to some documentation? Also, is it correct to say that AccessType.FIELD does not work for the @Parent annotated field? And thus it always needs a public getter and setter?

Comment: I find this from the official documentation link  : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/ , section 2.4.3.4. @Parent .But I don't know why it will not work .The user property in the profile object always remains null

Comment: The @Parent mapping would be great, if only it would support FIELD access, which it apparently does not. The @Parent mapping only worked when I added both a public getter and setter for User. Thus it does not offer any benefit over a pure JPA solution as described by CP1R8. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I find that even when I add `@Parent` hibernate treats it like it needs to add the field in ddl generation... don't know if it'd be a problem if I weren't using it for ddl generation.

Comment: As @Kdeveloper said you need getter/setter method to make it work. Hopefully with Hibernate 5 setter can be protected.