# JPA: How can an @Embeddable object get a reference back to its owner, but the @Embeddable is in a lazy collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know that if you want to reference back from [@Embeddable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) to its parent you can set the parent "manually" in the setter and use [@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html#PROPERTY) for this embedded field as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060891/jpa-how-can-an-embeddable-object-get-a-reference-to-its-owner), but what if this embedded element is mapped in a collection, which is lazy loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Actually not sure whether this is an issue, if not "manually" reference back from @embeddable to its parent, everything is fine.

[@CollectionTable.JoinColumns()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html#joinColumns()) is used to set the foreign key columns of the collection table which reference the primary table of the entity, which means that once set this optional property, there is no necessary to "manually" reference back from @embeddable to its parent.

Use your case as example:

```
@Entity
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

....

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "COMPUTERS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_IMAGE"))
    private List<Computer> computers;
}

@Embeddable
public class Computer {

    @Column
    private String ipAddress;

    *****//This idImage field is not necessary
    @Column(name = "ID_IMAGE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Long idImage;*****

}
```

Once comment out the field idImage and its @Column annotation, the generated SQL is:

```
create table IMAGES (
           id bigint not null,
            Name_Image varchar(255),
            primary key (id)
        )

create table COMPUTERS (
       ID_IMAGE bigint not null,
        ipAddress varchar(255)
    )

 alter table COMPUTERS
   add constraint FKl1ucm93ttye8p8i9s5cgrurh
   foreign key (ID_IMAGE)
   references IMAGES
```

If "manually" declare the join column in the embeddable class, although the DDL are the same, the embeddable object will contain one extra field "imageId", which will cause the JDBC call parameter out of index when executing the INSERT operation.